# How to handle multiplayer games with a PHP backend?

Tags: php, android, ios

I'm supposed to write a PHP backend that handles a multiplayer game for Android and iOS where users from both platforms to be able to play together.

I'm new to sockets in PHP, and couldn't find any case where a PHP backend was used to handle this type of services, the question is, if it's not PHP that we need then what? what server handle these types of games?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of use case falls right into the sweet spot for [node js](http://nodejs.org/) because of its impressive abilities to handle sockets and concurrency. If it is possible to switch over to node I strongly recommend it. If you're stuck with php your options are pretty limitted. Two of them are [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) and [PHPdaemon](http://daemon.io/#mainfeatures)